# Loading image server node.js

Tags: image, node.js

im trying to load image and when I check on the browser if works, it say not found, any ideas of how to fixed.

Thank you

```
var http = require('http');

var body;

exports.handle = function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'image/png',
    'Content-Length': body.length
  });
  res.end(img, 'binary');
};

exports.init = function(cb) {
  require('fs').readFile('./image.png', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    body = data;
    cb();
  });
}
```

Comment: And why would you do that? The readfile function is async, and it returns the binary data, probably as a buffer. Why aren't you just outputting an image tag with the source set to the image on the server ?

Comment: " it returns the binary data" ? noo... read the doc my friend! it return a buffer by default. Your image is in a buffer, and you write your response in binary... do: `res.end(img, null)`

Comment: @CydGy - I have read the docs, and have read image files with FS, and image files are usually binary data, and my comment explicitly states that it's most likely returned as a buffer, as that is what Node returns by default, a buffer with binary data. Jeezes!